# I want to send "Form data" from wordpress and save it in the Bitrix24 CRM

Tags: wordpress, dynamics-crm, integration-testing, bitrix

I am using a Hustle form in wordpress. So, There are two fields in that form (Name and Email) along with one hidden field (which user can't fill and has a fixed value e.g., audience). So, I want to save these three values in three different fields of Bitrix24 CRM. I was able to successfully integrate the first two fields (Name and email) using webhooks, but third field is where I am facing problem. I want to save the hidden field's value in this field of Bitrix24 CRM.

[image: CRM Field where I want to save hidden field's data]

I want to select one of the options while integrating form data. For name and email, I used the following code to map the fields:

```
"NAME" => $form_data['Name'], 
"EMAIL" => array(array("VALUE" => $form_data['email'], "VALUE_TYPE" => "WORK" )),
```

But the same approach isn't working in the third field. I think I am missing somewhere. Please help me out in this. I am also providing the link to the file where you can find all the field related information of my Bitrix24 CRM.

https://github.com/hemant1171/debugfiles/blob/main/CRM%20Fields%20List%20Response

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Hustle form works, but if you place code here, maybe i can help.
Are you indicating enumeration id?

Comment: This is typical text of a comment, not an answer. Please put your comment in the right place ("Add a comment") and consider deleting this one.